# detailed bash script with cp and grep will not work with spaces in filenames

Tags: bash, grep, cp, whitespace

I would never do it myself but people with Windows machines insist on putting spaces in filenames.

I've composed this detailed command which works perfectly except for the files with spaces in them. Have tried everything, single quotes, double quotes, ticks, escape with backslash.

The command is supposed to copy everything from a directory with certain file extensions, except a list of files which I don't want copied. Unfortunately some of those files contain spaces. This is the command:

```
cp $(ls *.txt *.docx | grep --invert-match --fixed-strings \
-e not_this_one.txt \
-e not_this_one_either.docx \
-e "no not me.txt" \
-e "please leave me out as well.docx")  ./destination_directory/
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find` and `xargs` instead of `$(...)` parameter expansion:

```
find *.txt *.docx \( \
      -name not_this_one.txt \
      -o -name not_this_one_either.docx \
      -o -name 'no not me.txt' \
      -o -name "please leave me out as well.docx" \
    \) -prune -o -print0 |
  xargs -0 cp -t /tmp/destination_directory
```

We use the `-prune` option to exclude things we don't want to copy.

We use `-print0` on the find command to produce NUL-terminated filenames, which when piped to `xargs -0` correctly handles filenames that contain whitespace.

Finally, we use the `-t <target_directory>` option on `cp` because this allows `xargs` to just append a list of filenames to the command (without the `-t`, the destination directory needs to come last, which complicates things a bit).

---

Or, use `tar`:

```
tar -cf- \
    --exclude=not_this_one.txt \
    --exclude='not_this_one_either.docx' \
    --exclude='no not me.txt' \
    --exclude='please leave me out as well.docx' *.txt *.docx |
  tar -C /tmp/destination_directory -xf-
```

(And of course, you could put your list of exclude patterns into a
file and use `--exclude-from` instead.)

Comment: Since you’re using `cp -t`, you could use `find -exec` directly instead of piping to `xargs`.

Comment: Yup. I just like xargs :). It's easy to write something using `find -exec` that will perform much more poorly than piping to `xargs`.

Comment: In this case, I doubt that `-exec cp -t /tmp/destination_directory {} +` would be slower than piping to `xargs`...

Comment: Yes, it works, only tested the first one. Also works with `mv`. I use the `find` command in simpler ways, and there's some useful stuff in there I've never seen before like `cp -t`. Still, I'm a beginner with bash, and next time I need to do something like this I'll try first to do it from python. Did not test the second command, but `tar` is more a compression and archiving command so not sure why you would use it for this.

Comment: If you want you can delete out the `/tmp/` which was not part of the original question. Maybe that path needs a dot . at the beginning of it.

Comment: @cardamom tar is very commonly used for bulk copying of files, just like this. Because it transforms your files into a stream, it's particularly useful when you need to copy over a network (e.g., from one computer to another, or from a container to the host).

Answer (score 1):

Once you send `ls *.txt *.docx` tru a pipe `|` the shell is generating **an string** where files are not separated. Well, they could be separated by spaces (or newlines), which leads to confusion of the next tool that try to use such string splitting filenames on spaces (or newlines).

Since you are tagging the question with bash, the expansion of the globs `*.txt` and `*.docx` is done by the shell (bash), and bash is able to reject some file patterns given in GLOBIGNORE, you can simply do:

```
( GLOBIGNORE='not_this_one.txt:not_this_one_either.docx:no not me.txt:please leave me out as well.docx';
  echo \
  cp -t /tmp/destination_directory *.txt *.docx
)
```

The `(...)` here is to ensure that the setting of GLOBIGNORE is erased once the subshell is closed. Of course, you can remove it and do a `unset GLOBIGNORE` after. The echo is there to show you the result of the command. If you are happy with what you get, remove the echo.